# OS X Java maximum threads per process

Tags: java, multithreading, macos, osx-mountain-lion

Running this code

```
        for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++) {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(60000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            System.out.println(i);
        }
```

results in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create new native thread
    at java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:658)
    at com.codeoverdrive.burnbearburn.Main.main(Main.java:10)
```

after 2024 running threads.
Playing with JVM heap and stack sizes does not help.

```
sysctl kern.num_threads
```

returns

```
kern.num_threads: 10240
```

OS X Mountain Lion 10.8.4,
Macbook Air with 4GB RAM

Any suggestions?

Comment: By the way you can `TimeUnit.MINUTES.sleep(1);`

Comment: @fge increasing permgen does not help because it is used for class definitions and associated metadata.

Answer (score 3):

The most probable cause is that the user you are running with has a limit on the number of threads it can create.

Try and increase this limit. The current limit can be shown by the `ulimit -u` command. Note that as a regular user you probably won't be able to increase it, you'll have to modify the environment as root.

And yes, `OutOfMemoryError` is misleading in this case.

Comment: `ulimit -u` shows max users processes count, not threads. And I do not know why, but setting it does not changes it's value.

Comment: It also influences the number of threads! At least on Linux it does. And yes, it is normal that you cannot change it as a user.